# How to configure "Kubernetes KMS plugin for Azure Key Vault" with Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-keyvault, azure-aks

I am working with Kubernetes on Azure.  I created and configured the [Azure Kubernetes Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/kubernetes-service/) and [Azure Container Registry](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/container-registry/) with the [Azure command line interface (CLI)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli) - I have a repository full of Azure CLI bash scripts that create/destroy my cloud infrastructure.

I plan to deploy to Kubernetes using [Helm](https://helm.sh/).  I plan to use [Helm Secrets](https://github.com/futuresimple/helm-secrets) to encrypt secrets and I am hoping I can use [Azure Key Vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/key-vault/) to store the encryption keys that encrypt/decrypt the "secrets".

I am now trying to create and configure the Azure Key Vault to work with Azure Kubernetes Service.  I can see how I could create a Key Vault with the Azure CLI but the documentation for [kubernetes-kms](https://github.com/Azure/kubernetes-kms#-acs-engine) suggests that if you configure Kubernetes a certain way then the Key Vault will be automatically created and this will be configured to communicate with Azure Kubernetes Service.

> "We have added this feature to aks-engine so that you do not have to
>   worry about any of the manual steps to set this up."

[The documentation talks about editing a "kubernetesConfig"](https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine/blob/master/docs/topics/features.md#azure-key-vault-data-encryption), I've not seen a *"kubernetesConfig"* anywhere yet - I guess that is what you would have if you created your components using Azure Resource Manager (ARM) Templates.

**How do I get Azure Key Vault working with [kubernetes-kms](https://github.com/Azure/kubernetes-kms#-acs-engine) using Azure CLI?**

e.g. adding *enableEncryptionWithExternalKms* to the Kubernetes configuration and adding an *objectId* attribute to the service principal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot do that with AKS. You dont have access to masters to configure them.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for putting me right - I had assumed "aks-engine" was Azure Kubernetes Service.  I see now it is self managed Kubernetes cluster configured using ARM templates.  I will investigate the FlexVolume based approach instead.